# How to set user password using SHA-512 hash with Puppet?

Tags: linux, puppet, redhat

I want to set user password with Puppet. The code:

```
if ($operatingsystemmajrelease == '7') {
  group { 'zabbix':
    name   => "zabbix",
    ensure => "present",
  }
  user { 'zabbix':
    name     => "zabbix",
    groups   => "zabbix",
    password => "$6$UdvUfiKs$rb4XFkCn2h/AUZrJsg2wnRDkOH5E5lliJZXqySVEYUDARFSlWKYHOeMLWycTa2jIMa3XQ3MWtq1EiilBZCbKX.",
  }
}
```

produces an error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Illegal variable name, The given name 'UdvUfiKs' does not conform to the naming rule /^((::)?[a-z]\w*)*((::)?[a-z_]\w*)$/ at /opt/puppetlabs/environments/Linux_nieprodukcja/modules/zabbix_install_lin/manifests/init.pp:16:20 on node napupp01.corpnet.pl","issue_kind":"RUNTIME_ERROR"}

SHA-512 I've generated form shell `passwd zabbix` after adding user zabbix and copied it to manifest. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are using double quotes in your `password` attribute for your `user` resource. This instructs Puppet to interpolate variables, among other actions. Puppet interprets your leading `$` as the beginning of a variable name and not a SHA-512 hash. You would have to do string escapes to help here. This behavior is common to all interpretive languages. You can easily fix this by using string literals instead with `''`:

```
user { 'zabbix':
  name     => 'zabbix',
  groups   => 'zabbix',
  password => '$6$UdvUfiKs$rb4XFkCn2h/AUZrJsg2wnRDkOH5E5lliJZXqySVEYUDARFSlWKYHOeMLWycTa2jIMa3XQ3MWtq1EiilBZCbKX.',
}
```

Note that puppet-lint would have alerted you to this issue with a warning and would have helped you to fix this: https://github.com/rodjek/puppet-lint.